# How can I make my image transition smoothly with matchedGeometryEffect?

Tags: animation, swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

The text will transition smoothly from left to right.
The image will also transition smoothly from left to right, however it decides to fade out/fade in. Because it is the exact same image, I want the image to stay solid and not transparent in the animation. Can this be accomplished? Or is this a flaw in matchedGeometryEffect?

```
struct MainView: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @State private var isFlipped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isFlipped {
                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: animation)
                Image("Logo")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "icon", in: animation)
            } else {
                Image("Logo")
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "icon", in: animation)
                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: animation)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                isFlipped.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a "hack" to make it work. Somehow using 'identity' will still ignore the transition falling back to its default fading the views in and out. Somehow telling the `asymmetric` to the exact same thing does work. Perhaps someone has a logical explanation for this, cause I don't.

```
extension AnyTransition {
    static var identityHack: AnyTransition {
        .asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .identity)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @Namespace private var animation
    @State private var isFlipped = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isFlipped {
                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: animation)
                Image("Logo")
                    .transition(.identityHack)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "icon", in: animation)
            } else {
                Image("Logo")
                    .transition(.identityHack)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "icon", in: animation)
                Text("text")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: animation)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                isFlipped.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange that we don't have just a simple option for this out of the box...